# Prevent default pdf reader open after call PrintTo c#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I'm trying to make a program that send pdf file to a thermal printer. The problem is that after the file has been sent to printer, the default PDF reader (foxit reader in this case) is always open up and unmanageable. And yes, I already spent days to search but nothing completely works for me.

Also, I have tried to turn off "View PDF Result" property on Foxit Reader PDF Printer but it seems does not work as well.

Here is my simple code:

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\test.pdf");
            info.Arguments = "\"XP-58\"";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            info.Verb = "PrintTo";

            PrintProcess p = new PrintProcess();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForInputIdle(1500);
            p.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I can completely close the pdf reader (foxit reader) or whatever using this way. But, still looking for another can be do this task silently without open then close it.

```
private static bool KillAdobe(string name)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses().Where(
                     clsProcess => clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith(name)))
        {
            clsProcess.Kill();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```